# Evaluation inside Button stops after some seconds

Tags: dynamic, button

I would like to trigger a long calculation inside a dynamic module with a Button. It seems that the evaluation stops without an error-message after some seconds.
I made a test outside the a dynamic module:

```
Clear[res]
Button["run", res = Total[Table[i; Pause[1], {i, 1, 3}]]]
```

After pressing the button, the result is:
3 Null

Ok but if the calculation takes 6 seconds

```
Clear[res]
Button["run", res = Total[Table[i; Pause[1], {i, 1, 6}]]]
```

Then res is not assigned.

Why does it happen and how can it be avoided, also inside a DynamicModule.
I would like something like this:

- Button to start a simulation run
- Another Button which does some analysis on the simulation results

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behaviour is explained in the documentation of `Button` under `Examples > Options > Method`. By default, button functions are evaluated on a preemptive link which times out after 5 seconds. To prevent the code from timing out you can set `Method -> "Queued"` which will run the code on the main link.

Comment: You can also directly change the `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` option value, but that is not recommended - http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Apr/msg00490.html

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with a SetterBar instead of a Button - Method option does not exist for SetterBar.