# manipulate: time limit on calculations

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I'd like to disable the 5 second time limit in the manipulate construct. I read about setting

```
    SynchronousUpdating -> False
```

But for some reason this does not apply to Evaluations within controls:

```
    Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {{a, 1}, Button["set a", Pause[6]; a = 2;] &}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

In the above example a is not set to 2 when pressing the button. When the Pause timespan is set to 5 or below, a is actually set to 2.

Does anybody know how to fix that, i.e. how to disable the time limit for evaluations in controls?

Comment: See the option `Method -> "Queued"` in the ref. page for [Button](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Button.html), or these possible duplicate questions: [1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15602/dialog-inside-dynamic-module)
[2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/why-do-buttons-with-choicedialog-freeze-the-front-end)
[3)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7804/evaluation-inside-button-stops-after-some-seconds)

Comment: @Michael E2: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Maybe you want to add your answer as a real answer to this topic, so that I can give you credit for it and mark this topic answered.

Comment: Thanks for the thanks.  No worries about the credit.  The same answer (some with good explanations) can be found in the links in my first comment, so I expect this question will be closed as a duplicate.  This site tends to prefer to close duplicates and link them together, to help others who come to this site find the best answers in one place.

Comment: Sure thing. I was not sure at first if the problem was only dependent on the control or if some behavior of manipulate had something to do with it. My search for manipulate did not come up with anything so I posted the question.

Comment: No problem.  Knowing the answer makes it easier to search for the right question. :)  Now if someone searches and finds this question, they will be referred to another one that has good answers.